# How to compare a cell to multiple values?

Tags: excel

I want to assign multiple values to text using switch.
here it goes:

```
=switch (A1, 1|4|7, "A", 2|3|5, "B"...)
```

I know the or expression "|" is a programming language, but how do I express in excel?

I know there is OR() in excel, but I have to repeat A1= ... many times. I want to avoid.

Comment: Please explain your question properly, is 1,4,7 are sequence or what, as its not even number please breif question with sample file

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to setup a LOOKUP table like below.

e.g.

```
1    A
4    A
7    A
2    B
3    B
5    B
```

And then use a simple `VLOOKUP` like below

`=VLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$F$6,2,0)`

where range E1:F6 holds the LOOKUP table as shown.